# How to proprely instantiate DatatyProperties on Jena?

Tags: jena, ontology, owl

I wrote the following Jena code. But It is an error and I didn't know how to address this.

Here is the code

```
Resource   subject   = null;
Property   property  = null;
Statement  statement = null;

...

OntModel domainModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ProfileRegistry.OWL_DL_LANG);
domainModel.read((new FileInputStream(bootstrapInOwl)), null);

subject = domainModel.getIndividual(bootbase + "Frame" + frameNum);                     
property = domainModel.getOntProperty(bootbase + "hasDuration");                
statement = domainModel.createLiteralStatement(subject, property, 12000);
domainModel.add(statement);
```

Here is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.StatementImpl.<init>(StatementImpl.java:29)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.createStatement(ModelCom.java:1116)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.createLiteralStatement(ModelCom.java:626)
    at soctrace.Intology.manageOntologies2(Intology.java:217)
    at soctrace.Intology.main(Intology.java:56)
```

The property `hasDuration` domain's is `Frame` Class while his range is `int`.

Thanks for any reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one of the two lines below returns a `null` pointer:

```
subject = domainModel.getIndividual(bootbase + "Frame" + frameNum);                     
property = domainModel.getOntProperty(bootbase + "hasDuration");
```

Verify that you look for an existing URI.

Comment: yeah! that is it, the value of `frameNum` was changing unexpectedly !